# Android Image Asset Studio: icon showing white color of an image as greyish

Tags: android, android-assets

I wanted to create an icon for A+ (with + superscript).

I tried to create using image asset studio. But problem is i am not able to add superscript

So i have create a A+ image in gimp.

Then i created a app bar icon using android asset stuido. I got the following output. I am expecting the A+ to be pure white but it shows slightly greyish. I am also using search icon which shows pure white and text converted to icon which also shows pure white. So how to make to pure white

the below is the image:

[image]

My gimp image which i created is:

[image]

Comment: It looks an image with Alpha, can you verify?

Comment: I have uploaded the actual image

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `iconTint` attribute to the menu item in your `menu.xml` file:

```
        app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
```

If the icon still looks gray to you, it may have been imported with the `HOLO_LIGHT` theme (which seems to use lower opacity). Try importing the image asset again, making sure to select `HOLO_DARK` as the theme on the "Configure Image Asset" screen. This should give you a more opaque white icon.